# xcopy to "%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\" stated copied yet nothing is there

Tags: batch-file, cmd, xcopy

I'm trying to write a small bat script to put on my teams desktops and allow them to update their personal macro file with mine when ever I push out an update or have created new tools.

I have the following

xcopy "O:\abc Supply chain\Supply Chain Team\David Peters\Excel\Macro File" "%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\" /y

under CMD is says 1 files copied yet there isn't anything in the XLSTART folder.

can you pleased tell me what I'm doing wrong

many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure about your configuration, but for me the `Roaming` folder is already included in the value of the `%AppData%` variable.

```
"%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\"
           ^......^
```

So, probably you should use `"%AppData%\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\"`